# How can I get the top N solutions to a bin packing algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to find/create algorithm to pack bins and return back the top N solutions, not the "most" optimal one only.

Normal bin-packing is pretty straightforward, but it seems I need to add some type of algorithm over the top of it to try different configurations.

example. I have a list of items with varying sizes from 0.5 to 7.5 and need to figure out the top 5 solutions for bins that have a capacity of 20. Goal is minimal amount of bins.

results:

1. 7 bins, [x7 bin descriptions, with waste count]
2. 7 bins, [x7 bin descriptions, with waste count]
3. 8 bins, [x8 bin descriptions, with
   waste count]
4. 8 bins, [x8 bin descriptions, with waste count]
5. 8 bins, [x8 bin descriptions, with waste count]

Comment: You can exhaustively search, and thus keep the top solutions.

Comment: yeah, i guess that could work. as in, just iterate over every possible solution and keep an array of 10, only adding and pushing a new on off the array if it beats the lowest bin count of the last one in the array?

Comment: Right -- you use the same algorithm, but your "memory" for an optimal solution expands from one item to 5 or 10.  When you check to see whether you want to keep a new-found solution, you check against the *bottom* of that list.